# proof question on sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

suppose that $(a_n) → a$ and $(b_n) → b$. Show that for all $c, d ∈ R$ we
have
$(ca_n + db_n)$ → $ca + db$ .

Thanks, i have no idea where to start or continue with this problem.

Comment: If you show that $(a_n + b_n) \rightarrow a + b$ and $(ca_n) \rightarrow ca$, using the knowledge that $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$ (use the definition of convergence of sequences $\forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \forall_{n > N} |a_n - a| < \epsilon$), you've made a big step forward.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the definition of limit. You want to show that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, it holds that 
$$
|c a_n + d b_n - (c a + d b)|=|c(a_n-a)+d(b_n-b)|<\varepsilon
$$
for all $n$ large enough, i.e. for $n\geq n_0$ for some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$. 
You know that
$$|a_n-a|< \frac{\varepsilon}{2c} \text{ and } |b_n-b|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2d} $$
for $n$ large enough. Use that.